# I cant run my react native app after send to test flight

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, watchman

I'm developing an application with react native and I recently published it on the test flight for my beta testers to use the application, but now I need to continue developing but when  I run

```
react-native run-ios
```

the application is installed on the emulator but the error appears:

> Could not connect to development server.
>
> Ensure the following:
>
> - Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
> - Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
> - WiFi is enabled and connected to the same network as the Node Server
>
> URL: http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=br.com.W2App
>
> RCT Fatal
> __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
> _dispatch_call_block_and_release
> _dispatch_client_callout
> _dispatch_main_queue_drain
> _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
> **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
> __CFRunLoopRun
> CFRunLoopRunSpecific
> GSEventRunModal
> -[UIApplication _run]
> UIApplicationMain
> main
> start_yes
> 0x0
> 0x0

In the output log in the terminal appears:

> 2022-12-23 16:16:32.957 xcodebuild[44831:5288964] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x13bb0fc60: name:Docs.docc path:group:Docs.docc> Failed to load container at path : /Users/goattech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/W2App-bcybuxjmeijubwcppznzxbonxojg/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-protobuf/Sources/protoc-gen-swift/Docs.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}
>
> 2022-12-23 16:16:38.199 xcodebuild[44831:5290006] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.InterfaceBuilderBuildSupport.PlatformDefinition
>
> info Installing "/Users/goattech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/W2App-bcybuxjmeijubwcppznzxbonxojg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/W2App.app"
>
> info Launching "br.com.W2App"
>
> success Successfully launched the app on the simulator
>
> ✨ Done in 111.36s.

I already changed the ios scheme from release to debug back but that didn't help, I need to run the app in development mode inside the IOS emulator

Comment: I solve that going in xcode -> Product -> Schemes -> Edit Scheme -> Analyze -> set Build configuration to Debug